# Output not correctly being written to CSV

Tags: c#, .net

So I am having an issue with my output being written to a CSV file. The output to this code is in the correct format when being written to the CSV file but it is only entering a single row in the file. There should be much more. Around 150 lines. Current out put is:

> (859.85    7N830127 185)

Which is correct, but there should be more of these. It seems like to me that it is only writing the first line of the parsed EDI file and then stopping. I need to find a way to make sure it writes all data that is being parsed can anyone help me?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("edifile.txt");

    string[] ediMapTemp = sr.ReadLine().Split('|');
    List<string[]> ediMap = new List<string[]>();
    List<object[]> outputMatrix = new List<object[]>();

    foreach (var line in ediMapTemp)
    {
        ediMap.Add(line.Split('~'));
    }

    DetailNode node = new DetailNode(0, null, 0);
    int hierarchicalDepth = 0;
    int hierarchicalIdNumber;
    int hierarchicalParentIdNumber;
    int hierarchicalLevelCode;
    int hierarchicalChildCode = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ediMap.Count; i++)
    {
        string segmentHeader = ediMap[i][0];
        if (segmentHeader == "HL")
        {
            hierarchicalIdNumber = Convert.ToInt32(ediMap[i][1]);
            hierarchicalParentIdNumber = Convert.ToInt32(ediMap[i][2]);
            hierarchicalLevelCode = Convert.ToInt32(ediMap[i][3]);
            hierarchicalChildCode = Convert.ToInt32(ediMap[i][4]);

            List<string[]> levelDetails = new List<string[]>();
            for (int v = i + 1; v < ediMap.Count; v++)
            {
                if (ediMap[v][0] == "HL") break;
                levelDetails.Add(ediMap[v]);
            }
            DetailNode getNode = node.Find(node, hierarchicalParentIdNumber);
            getNode.headList.Add(new DetailNode(hierarchicalIdNumber, levelDetails, getNode.depth + 1));
        }
    }
    node.Traversal(new VID(), node);
    foreach (var vid in VIDList.vidList)

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("Import.csv"))
        {
            //probably a loop here
            writer.WriteLine(String.Join(",", vid.totalCurrentCharges, vid.assetId, vid.componentName, vid.recurringCharge));
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick Review, should the code be the following:

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("Import.csv"))
{
    //a loop here
    foreach (var vid in VIDList.vidList)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(String.Join(",", vid.totalCurrentCharges, vid.assetId, vid.componentName, vid.recurringCharge));
    }
}
```

You would open the file once and then loop thru your collection, writing each one.

Comment: It doesn't like the  foreach (var vid in VIDList.vidList)

Comment: foreach (var vid in VIDList.vidList) is getting an error it states " the local variable 'vid' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to "vid" which is already used in a parent or current scope

Comment: This works now but is its not in a true csv formate it is showing up with each line on a new row

Comment: If you want a LONG continuous line, then you would use [Write](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.write(v=vs.110).aspx) which won't output carriage return / linefeed.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you're re-opening the output file for each line you're trying to write, so you're overwriting the output file with a new file for each line. That would mean only the last entry remains in the file. Try moving this line

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("Import.csv"))
```

Outside the foreach loop.